# android: How to open the call screen and fill it with a number but do not make a call?

Tags: android, phone-call

I could only find "how to make a call from your application" and the solution is:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
String s = et.getText().toString();

try {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + s));
    startActivity(callIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
    Log.d("Calling a Phone Number", "Call failed" + activityException);
    }
```

But this directly makes a call, without confirming. Like if the number must be preceded with a `0` user must be allowed to do it and then make a call and once the call is finished he must be taken back to the application activity where he started the intent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply change `Intent.ACTION_CALL` to `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` in your code.

**Update**:
To call just the phone use `Intent.ACTION_DIAL`, however `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` call messaging or phone.